# user editor, only edit the first record

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

I am working in a user editor, I have a problem, just edit the first record.

when I want to edit another different user it sends me data only from the first one
i.imgur.com/nhP8iKz.png

```
  public function usuarios(Request $request){
    $data = [
        'category_name' => 'apps',
        'page_name' => 'contacts',
        'has_scrollspy' => 0,
        'scrollspy_offset' => '',
    ];
 $usuarios = User::All();

    // $pageName = 'contacts';
    return view('usuarios',compact('usuarios'))->with($data);
}
public function userupdate(Request $request){
 

 foreach($request->service as $key=>$value){

    $nuevoIngreso = User::find($value['id']);
    if($nuevoIngreso){
    $nuevoIngreso->name = $value['name'];
    $nuevoIngreso->email = $value['email'];
    $nuevoIngreso->telefono = $value['telefono'];

    $nuevoIngreso->tipo = $value['tipo'];
    $nuevoIngreso->save();
    }
   }

    // $pageName = 'contacts';
    return redirect('usuarios')->with('mensaje', 'Ficha Actualizada.');
}
```

Blade.php

```
    @extends('layouts.app')



@section('content')
<div id="tableCheckbox" class="col-lg-12 col-12 layout-spacing">
                            <div class="statbox widget box box-shadow">
                                <div class="widget-header">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 mt-3 text-center">
                                            <h2>Usuarios</h2>
                                        </div>                       
                                    </div>
                                    
                                </div>
                                <div class="widget-content widget-content-area">
                                    <div class="table-responsive">
                                        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped table-checkable table-highlight-head mb-4">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th class="checkbox-column">
                                                        <label class="new-control new-checkbox checkbox-primary" style="height: 18px; margin: 0 auto;">
                                                            <input type="checkbox" class="new-control-input todochkbox" id="todoAll">
                                                            <span class="new-control-indicator"></span>
                                                        </label>
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th class="">Nombre</th>
                                                    <th class="">Email</th>
                                                    <th class="">Telefono</th>
                                                    <th class="text-center">ACCIÓNES</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                @foreach($usuarios as $key=>$users)
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="checkbox-column">
                                                        <label class="new-control new-checkbox checkbox-primary" style="height: 18px; margin: 0 auto;">
                                                            <input type="checkbox" class="new-control-input todochkbox" id="todo-1">
                                                            <span class="new-control-indicator"></span>
                                                        </label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <p class="mb-0">{{$users->name}}</p>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>{{$users->email}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{$users->telefono}}</td>

                                                    <td class="text-center">
                                                        <ul class="table-controls">
                                                            <li><a href="{{route('userupdate', $users)}}"  data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Settings" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registerModal"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-settings text-primary"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="3"></circle><path d="M19.4 15a1.65 1.65 0 0 0 .33 1.82l.06.06a2 2 0 0 1 0 2.83 2 2 0 0 1-2.83 0l-.06-.06a1.65 1.65 0 0 0-1.82-.33 1.65 1.65 0 0 0-1 1.51V21a2 2 0 0 1-2 2 2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-.09A1.65 1.65 0 0 0 9 19.4a1.65 1.65 0 0 0-1.82.33l-.06.06a2 2 0 0 1-2.83 0 2 2 0 0 1 0-2.83l.06-.06a1.65 1.65 0 0 0 .33-1.82 1.65 1.65 0 0 0-1.51-1H3a2 2 0 0 1-2-2 2 2 0 0 1 2-2h.09A1.65 1.65 0 0 0 4.6 9a1.65 1.65 0 0 0-.33-1.82l-.06-.06a2 2 0 0 1 0-2.83 2 2 0 0 1 2.83 0l.06.06a1.65 1.65 0 0 0 1.82.33H9a1.65 1.65 0 0 0 1-1.51V3a2 2 0 0 1 2-2 2 2 0 0 1 2 2v.09a1.65 1.65 0 0 0 1 1.51 1.65 1.65 0 0 0 1.82-.33l.06-.06a2 2 0 0 1 2.83 0 2 2 0 0 1 0 2.83l-.06.06a1.65 1.65 0 0 0-.33 1.82V9a1.65 1.65 0 0 0 1.51 1H21a2 2 0 0 1 2 2 2 2 0 0 1-2 2h-.09a1.65 1.65 0 0 0-1.51 1z"></path></svg></a> </li>
                                                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Edit"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-edit-2 text-success"><path d="M17 3a2.828 2.828 0 1 1 4 4L7.5 20.5 2 22l1.5-5.5L17 3z"></path></svg></a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Delete"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-trash-2 text-danger"><polyline points="3 6 5 6 21 6"></polyline><path d="M19 6v14a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H7a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V6m3 0V4a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v2"></path><line x1="10" y1="11" x2="10" y2="17"></line><line x1="14" y1="11" x2="14" y2="17"></line></svg></a></li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <div class="modal fade register-modal" id="registerModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="registerModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                        <div class="modal-content">

                                          <div class="modal-header" id="registerModalLabel">
                                            <h4 class="modal-title">Editar Usuario</h4>
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><svg aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-x"><line x1="18" y1="6" x2="6" y2="18"></line><line x1="6" y1="6" x2="18" y2="18"></line></svg></button>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="modal-body">
                                      
                                            <form id="addContactModalTitle" class="mt-0" method="POST" action="{{ route('userupdate') }}">
                                                    {{method_field('PUT')}}
@csrf
<input class="form-control" type="hidden" value="{{$users->id}}" name="service[{{$key}}][id]">
                                               <div class="form-group">
                                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-user"><path d="M20 21v-2a4 4 0 0 0-4-4H8a4 4 0 0 0-4 4v2"></path><circle cx="12" cy="7" r="4"></circle></svg>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" name="service[{{$key}}][name]" id="exampleInputUsername1" value="{{$users->name}}">
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-at-sign"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="4"></circle><path d="M16 8v5a3 3 0 0 0 6 0v-1a10 10 0 1 0-3.92 7.94"></path></svg>
                                                <input type="email" class="form-control mb-2" name="service[{{$key}}][email]" id="exampleInputEmail2" value="{{$users->email}}">
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-lock"><rect x="3" y="11" width="18" height="11" rx="2" ry="2"></rect><path d="M7 11V7a5 5 0 0 1 10 0v4"></path></svg>
                                                <input type="phone" class="form-control mb-4" name="service[{{$key}}][telefono]" id="exampleInputPassword2" value="{{$users->telefono}}">
                                              </div>
                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-lock"><rect x="3" y="11" width="18" height="11" rx="2" ry="2"></rect><path d="M7 11V7a5 5 0 0 1 10 0v4"></path></svg>
                                                <input type="phone" class="form-control mb-4" name="service[{{$key}}][tipo]" id="exampleInputPassword2" value="{{$users->tipo}}">
                                              </div>
                                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-2 mb-2 btn-block">Actualizar</button>
                                            </form>

                                           

                                          </div>
                                         
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                             @endforeach
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>

                                  

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


      

   @endsection
```

Routes:

```
 Route::get('usuarios','HomeController@usuarios');
Route::put('/usuarios', 'HomeController@userupdate' )->name('userupdate');
```

if necessary I can upload a screenshot of the problem to better understand.

When I click on edit the user ID = 2, or 3 sends me data from the user ID 1 only. in list it prints all the records, but in the form it only prints the first user

Comment: Do you want to edit all the users? or just one user?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/nhP8iKz.png I want to edit the user that I select in the list

Answer (score 0):

You are getting all users. Try passing the user id and get only that user data.

```
Route::get('usuarios/{id}','HomeController@usuarios');

public function usuarios($id){
 $data = [
    'category_name' => 'apps',
    'page_name' => 'contacts',
    'has_scrollspy' => 0,
    'scrollspy_offset' => '',
 ];

 $usuarios = User::findOrFail($id);

 // $pageName = 'contacts';
 return view('usuarios',compact('usuarios'))->with($data); 
}
```

Pass id as a parameter in the URL, and get the data specific to that id. Then update for that id.